# CloudKit - How to share multiple records and retrieve shared records?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I watched last [WWDC 2016 What's New with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226) to understand how to share records with other users using **CKShare**

**Single record sharing:**

I am able to share and retrieve a single record

i.e if *xyz@gmail.com* has created and shared a single record to *abc@gmail.com*

**Multiple records sharing:**

let's say there are 10 records and *xyz@gmail.com* wants to share to  *abc@gmail.com*. I am facing the issue when user *xyz@gmail.com* shares multiple records to user *abc@gmail.com*

**What I have tried so far:**

First I created 3 note records:

Note1

Note2 ( set parent as Note1 )

Note3 ( set parent as Note1 )

I shared Note1 ( Parent record ) with below code:

**CODE - Share record**

```
let controller = UICloudSharingController { controller,
        preparationCompletionHandler in

        let share = CKShare(rootRecord: self.parentRecord!)
        share[CKShareTitleKey] = "note" as CKRecordValue
        share.publicPermission = .readOnly

        let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(
              recordsToSave: [self.parentRecord!, share],
              recordIDsToDelete: nil)

        operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = { (record, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("CloudKit error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, recordIDs, error in

            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
            } else{
                print("Success")
                preparationCompletionHandler(share,CKContainer.default(), error)
            }
        }

        CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.add(operation)

    }

    controller.availablePermissions = [.allowPrivate, .allowReadOnly]
    controller.delegate = self
    present(controller, animated: true)
```

and retrieved shared-note with below code:

**CODE - Read data from shared-note**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith cloudKitShareMetadata: CKShareMetadata) {
    let acceptSharesOperation = CKAcceptSharesOperation(
        shareMetadatas: [cloudKitShareMetadata])

    acceptSharesOperation.perShareCompletionBlock = {
        metadata, share, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {

            let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(
                recordIDs: [cloudKitShareMetadata.rootRecordID])

            operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = { record, _, error in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }

                if let shareRecord = record {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        // Shared record successfully fetched. Update user
                        // interface here to present to user.
                        print("\(shareRecord["id"]!)") // id of note
                        print("\(shareRecord["text"])") // text of note
                        print("Shared record successfully fetched")
                    }
                }
            }

            operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { (recordsWithRecordIDs,error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }else {
                    if let recordsWithRecordIDs = recordsWithRecordIDs {
                        print("Count \(recordsWithRecordIDs.count)")
                    }
                }
            }
            CKContainer.default().sharedCloudDatabase.add(operation)
        }
    }

    CKContainer(identifier: cloudKitShareMetadata.containerIdentifier)
        .add(acceptSharesOperation)
}
```

Above method gives only parent note data ( root/parent only )

**Queries:**

1) How to fetch other children note records? ( I used term children for understanding purpose )

2) Do I need to check every time whether there are new shared records or not

As I haven't found any good tutorials and the source from official Apple docs. Would you suggest me the approach to share and retrieve multiple records?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe Thunk's answer is incorrect, since you should not have to fetch any records with the parent reference to a given record. First, where would you search? The child records of the CKShare root record *do not* appear in your shared database and you don't have access to the other user's private zone. Luckily, CloudKit will push to you all child records referenced by the CKShare's root record. The following approach will also solve the second problem, you will be notified of any and all future changes automatically!

The key is to simply add a `CKDatabaseSubscription` to the shared database in the CloudKit container. Let's assume you are the client. Anytime another user share's a record with you, the CKShare record and the underlying root record referenced by the share are both situated in a custom zone in that user's private database. When you accept the share (triggering an application delegate method `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith`), the *same* CKShare and underlying record are now visible to you, except that they are both visible in your *shared* database. If you have subscribed to the shared database, the subscription will kick in and notify you right after you accept the share. Now you can fetch all changes in the shared database using `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation`. In the `recordZoneWithIDChangedBlock`, the `CKRecordZoneID` of the sharing user's custom zone will be given. You use this to trigger a `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation` (be sure to perform this operation in the shared database!), which returns the CKShare, the underlying root record, and *all records that have a parent reference to the underlying referenced record*.

So with a simple database subscription you can automatically trigger and download all shares, root records, and children!

Comment: Thanks for ur answer I will try ur approach and let you know

Comment: @r-carney This description was very helpful, though I'm still a bit confused. Which method in `CKFetchRecordZonesOperation` returns the actual changed records? Do you happen to have an example of this somewhere? Thank you!

Comment: @Clifton Labrum There is not much help I found when I was making a demo app I don't have a sample code now..go through apple's doc it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1, to find the records that have references to the parent, you'll need to create a query that checks the reference field for rootRecordID. This page from Apple has a section discussing retrieval options with code examples.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/AddingReferences/AddingReferences.html

Regarding question 2, you could constantly poll the server for updated records, but Apple discourages that in one of the WWDC videos since it generates a lot of network traffic (and thus burns through your monthly quota). I suggest adding a subscription notice on the CKshare. That way, you'll be notified when you need to fetch records.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I am able to set CKReference to child records, but I am still confused how would I fetch these records ( when user to whom I shared records clicks on shared link )

Comment: as there is only 1 method in AppDelegate in which parent record is received from meta data

Comment: It may be a couple if days before I can post an example, but I'll try to describe the approach here: the subscription will fire a notification. You get the recordID of the parent record from the notification. You then query all other records where the reference field equals that recordID.

Comment: Thanks...I am able to fetch all shared records from the zone...why can't I delete parent record as it gives me error "Reference Violation"..any idea?

Comment: That's interesting, I've never seen that error, but you're the second person to mention it recently here on SO. I haven't moved to IOS 11 yet and now I'm dreading That Apple broke something. That might be worth it's own question with relevant code and screenshots of the schema from the dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for ur help..let me post question to forum..Ur answer help me to solve my queries so I am going to accept it..!